# When NSStream NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable event called?

Tags: ios, camera, avcapturesession, nsstream, multipeer-connectivity

I cant really understand this event.
I'm hoping that it is **called when the sending queue** (or something similar internal structure) **is done sending previously written packets**.

Is it a correct assumption?

---

I'm working on a video streamer over Multipeer connectivity, and I want to use this property to decide if I should drop a camera frame (if there is no `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`), or I can submit it for `NSOutputStream`.

Imagine a BlueTooth connection, where I really need to drop a lot of camera frame, instead of submit every frame to `NSStream`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` event indicates that you can *write* (at least one byte!) to the stream without blocking. That does not mean that previously written data is completely
delivered to the other endpoint of the connection.

Comment: So I can't "use" it to work around Bluetooth lag, if I'm right.

Comment: Then what feature an NSStream embodies? Why is it better than create a timer, and send some data periodically from within? I can't really understand this class.

Comment: @Geri: Writing to a stream can *block* the current thread if the internal buffer is full. NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable tells you when it is OK to write.

Comment: It sounds the same as you'd keep polling it on a background thread. I really don't get it.

Comment: @Geri: You could write (synchronously) to the stream on a background thread. But a successful write operation also only means that the data has been written to the kernel buffer, not that is has been received from the other endpoint.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I got it. Frame dropping policy needs to be implemented on its own.

Comment: So we should wait until `HasSpaceAvailable` is received before we send more?

Comment: @macdonjo: Yes, if you want to avoid a blocking write call.